# ros-kinetic-moveit on arm64 board (Jetson TX1)

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using **Jetson TX1** board which is **arm64** based processor and I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 and **ROS-Kinetic** on it.

When I try installing **Moveit** Packages, I am below Errors some errors and unable to install those packages.

```
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-object-recognition-msgs/ros-kinetic-object-recognition-msgs_0.4.1-0xenial-20190323-031159-0800_arm64.deb
  Hash Sum mismatch


W: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-octomap-msgs/ros-kinetic-octomap-msgs_0.3.3-0xenial-20181107-161457-0800_arm64.deb
  Hash Sum mismatch


W: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-moveit-msgs/ros-kinetic-moveit-msgs_0.9.1-0xenial-20190323-035407-0800_arm64.deb
  Hash Sum mismatch


W: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-urdfdom-py/ros-kinetic-urdfdom-py_0.3.3-0xenial-20180811-092304-0800_arm64.deb
  Hash Sum mismatch


W: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-srdfdom/ros-kinetic-srdfdom_0.4.2-1xenial-20190322-171717-0800_arm64.deb
  Hash Sum mismatch


W: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-moveit-core/ros-kinetic-moveit-core_0.9.15-0xenial-20190323-095716-0800_arm64.deb
  Hash Sum mismatch


W: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-moveit-experimental/ros-kinetic-moveit-experimental_0.9.15-0xenial-20190323-111249-0800_arm64.deb
  Hash Sum mismatch


W: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-chomp-motion-planner/ros-kinetic-chomp-motion-planner_0.9.15-0xenial-20190323-114444-0800_arm64.deb
  Hash Sum mismatch


W: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-moveit-ros-perception/ros-kinetic-moveit-ros-perception_0.9.15-0xenial-20190323-111401-0800_arm64.deb
  Hash Sum mismatch


W: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-moveit-ros-planning/ros-kinetic-moveit-ros-planning_0.9.15-0xenial-20190323-120721-0800_arm64.deb
  Hash Sum mismatch


W: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-warehouse-ros/ros-kinetic-warehouse-ros_0.9.2-0xenial-20190322-232908-0800_arm64.deb
  Hash Sum mismatch


W: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-moveit-ros-warehouse/ros-kinetic-moveit-ros-warehouse_0.9.15-0xenial-20190323-132911-0800_arm64.deb
  Hash Sum mismatch


W: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-moveit-kinematics/ros-kinetic-moveit-kinematics_0.9.15-0xenial-20190323-133002-0800_arm64.deb
  Hash Sum mismatch


W: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-moveit-ros-move-group/ros-kinetic-moveit-ros-move-group_0.9.15-0xenial-20190323-140418-0800_arm64.deb
  Hash Sum mismatch


W: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-moveit-ros-manipulation/ros-kinetic-moveit-ros-manipulation_0.9.15-0xenial-20190323-144837-0800_arm64.deb
  Hash Sum mismatch


W: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-moveit-ros-planning-interface/ros-kinetic-moveit-ros-planning-interface_0.9.15-0xenial-20190323-151853-0800_arm64.deb
  Hash Sum mismatch


W: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-moveit-commander/ros-kinetic-moveit-commander_0.9.15-0xenial-20190323-155244-0800_arm64.deb
  Hash Sum mismatch
```

How can I resolve these errors and install the MoveIt Packages in the Jetson Board.

Kindly help.

Thanks,

Radesh

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/326218/ros-kinetic-moveit-on-arm64-board-(jetson-tx1)/) by [Radeshwar](https://answers.ros.org/users/32196/radeshwar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2019-06-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-19**:\

> ( Image attached here -- > https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Flc...)

do not post screenshots of terminals. This is against the [Support guidelines](http://wiki.ros.org/Support) and also completely unnecessary: it's all text, so copy-paste the text into your question.

Edit your question to add the text. Use the `edit` button/link for that.

Finally: make sure to use the *Preformatted Text* button to properly format and layout the console text (it's the one with `101010` on it).

**Comment by [Radeshwar](https://answers.ros.org/users/32196/radeshwar/) on 2019-06-19**:
@gvdhoorn : I apologize, I wasn't aware about it.
I have made the modifications as per the guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's likely `sudo apt update` also doesn't succeed.

Pay attention to the output of `apt update`.

You're probably running into #q325039.

Update the keys, run `sudo apt update` and try again.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Radeshwar](https://answers.ros.org/users/32196/radeshwar/) on 2019-06-19**:
This worked :)
Thank you so much.
I appreciate your support.